# Difference between "notable" and "noteworthy"

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

Which would be more appropriate in this case?

> I currently do not have any affiliation that would be **notable** in the context of this election
>
> I currently do not have any affiliation that would be **noteworthy** in the context of this election

Or maybe something else altogether?

Comment: They're pretty much the same, but a pedant might argue that *notable* things/people are those which have already been "noted" by many, whereas *noteworthy* ones might just be deserving (in the opinion of the speaker) of attention they haven't necessarily got yet. Plus the possible implication that mere *notable* things aren't as important as those that are actually *worthy* of being noted.

Comment: ...plus your example suggests you may be using the wrong words anyway. Your examples might more naturally have used *notifiable* (or *relevant*, perhaps).

Comment: I would say the distinction is mainly when referring to *people*, when "notable" carries more positive connotation than "noteworthy". Churchill was notable; Hitler was noteworthy; Paris Hilton is neither.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the words *are* very similar and used in each other's definitions. For example, the main definition of **notable** is:

> Worthy or deserving of attention, **esp. on account of excellence, value, or importance**; significant in size or amount; noteworthy, remarkable, striking, signal, eminent.

While **noteworthy** has the main meaning:

> Worthy of attention, observation, or notice; notable, remarkable.

Note, however the bolded portion of the definition for *notable*--it refers to something as being noticeably and especially *great*, while something can be *noteworthy* without having excellence. That is, according to these definitions something which is *notable* is *noteworthy* for being good. Further, a person can be *notable* but not *noteworthy*.

However, in common use when talking about something (rather than someone), the two terms are used interchangeably. In your context, I would suggest different terms for different tones. You could use **notable** because of its connotations of importance. However, to erase possible grandeur by giving yourself this importance, you might use **noteworthy**.

Answer (score -3):

The question is well put, unintentionally perhaps, as
- notable is broader and pre-established
- noteworthy *in this context* is exactly that; some things are noteworthy in a context when in most contexts they are, perhaps, not

Notable may, in the context, not be noteworthy, but is still (and will remain) notable

Comment: I haven't been this confused since "The dog the girl the boy knew saw ran away."

Comment: Language and Boolean algebra come close? Sorry to hear that you did not make sense of the examples (I don't mean to be rude, but try again)

Comment: -1, because answers on an English language stackexchange should generally employ a correct use of the English language.